# Are there any books on the recruitment of scientists from the Third Reich (Operation "Paperclip" and others)?

Tags: world-war-two, science

Please advise the literature on the recruitment of scientists of the Third Reich after World War II ("Paperclip" and other operations).

Language: preferably Russian, but also English will do.

This topic is very interesting.

Comment: Hi dtn. Please note that, according to our site rules, reference requests are usually off-topic unless you are asking about primary sources. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidelines.

Comment: @Lars Bosteen
Hello! How to do it? The problem is just in the search for sources. Help correctly formulate a question.

Comment: For a start, you might look into the reference sections of relevant wikipedia articles. E.g. those about Manfred von Ardenne or Gustav Hertz.

Comment: You mentioned [Operation Paperclip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Paperclip) - it has quite a lot of references so you might find something useful there. Try also the [Russian language](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%C2%BB) version.

Comment: small addendum to my previous comment: http://cns.miis.edu/npr/pdfs/72pavel.pdf

Comment: Please read [Reference requests](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4132/1401) on why we don't support reference requests and [proposed reference request protocol](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4260/1401) for suggestions on how to revise your question to fit within our guidelines. As stated, the question is both a reference request and lacking in focus; there is no way to provide an authoritative answer.  Perhaps you could identify _questions you find interesting_ or _what is wrong with the resources you've already consulted?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Operation Paperclip**

There is the book operation paperclip: The Secret Intelligence Program that Brought Nazi Scientists to America. by Annie Jacobsen.

[Operation paperclip](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Operation-Paperclip-Intelligence-Program-Scientists/dp/0316277444)

> In the chaos following WWII, many of Germany's remaining resources were divvied up among allied forces. Some of the greatest spoils were the Third Reich's scientific minds--the minds that made their programs in aerospace and rocketry the best in the world. The United States secretly decided that the value of these former Nazis' forbidden knowledge outweighed their crimes, and the government formed a covert organization called Operation Paperclip to allow them to work without the knowledge of the American public.

> Drawing on exclusive interviews with dozens of Paperclip family members, with access to German archival documents (including, notably, papers available only to direct descendants of the former Third Reich's ranking members), files obtained through the Freedom of Information Act, and lost dossiers she recently discovered at the National Archives, Annie Jacobsen will follow more than a dozen German scientists through their postwar lives and into one of the most complex, nefarious, and jealously guarded government secrets of the 20th century.

[image: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Operation-Paperclip-Intelligence-Program-Scientists-ebook/dp/B010PA4UOG]

Comment: **If** you are listing secondary or tertiary sources, please try to describe them a little more. Content? Level of detail? Any detectable bias or viewpoint?

Comment: @o.m Ok, have removed the latter one is the latter did not really come with a description